# QT QLineEdit get negative numbers

Tags: c++, qt

I'm taking numbers from QLineEdit like this:

```
 int nem1 = ui -> lineedit -> text().toUInt();
```

but when I input a negative number like `-40`It shown 0 on debug. How can I allow takes negative numbers too?

Comment: `toUInt()` is to an unsigned int which can not have a negative number.

Answer (score 1):

The "U" in [toUInt()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstring.html#toUInt) stands for "unsigned", aka not negative.

To handle negative numbers, you'll want to call [toInt()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstring.html#toInt) instead.